# dotcloud helloworld deployment failed

Tags: dotcloud

i followed dotcloud hello world tutorial
install, enter api key, create app and push
and what i get is:

```
$ dotcloud push helloworld
# upload /Users/user/src/dotCloud ssh://dotcloud@uploader.dotcloud.com:443/helloworld
# rsync
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
building file list ... done
./
dotcloud.yml
index.html

sent 307 bytes  received 70 bytes  50.27 bytes/sec
total size is 149  speedup is 0.40
Deployment for "helloworld" triggered. Will be available in a few seconds.
2011-09-17 15:25:14 [api] Deploy helloworld scheduled for revision=latest
2011-09-17 15:25:14 [api] Waiting for the build. (It may take a few minutes)
2011-09-17 15:25:14 [www.0] Deploying...
2011-09-17 15:25:15 [www.0] Failed to be deployed, aborting...
2011-09-17 15:25:15 [api] Deploy finished

Deployment finished. Your application is available at the following URLs
error: No URL found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo easy_install pip && sudo pip install --upgrade dotcloud
```

solved it

Comment: We had a bug in the vhosts allocation subsystem, that would cause this deployment issue in some cases. We fixed it quite recently. I might be wrong, but I believe that the bugfix solved the issue, rather than the CLI upgrade. Well, the most important point is that it works now :-)